# Are there any references in the movie 'Jason Bourne' that acknowledge the continuity of 'The Bourne Legacy'?

Tags: reference, continuity, the-bourne-legacy, jason-bourne

*The Bourne Legacy* is the 4th film in the Bourne series but without Matt Damon. It tells a parallel story of a different kind of enhanced agent, while referencing the continued developments of characters in the previous three movies (for instance, Pam Landy).

However, *Jason Bourne* the fifth movie appears to entirely ignore the events of *The Bourne Legacy* (without contradicting it). It seems as if *The Bourne Legacy* is entirely redundant where *Jason Bourne* is concerned.

Are there **any** references in *Jason Bourne* that require or acknowledge the continuity of *The Bourne Legacy*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is - when Nicky Parsons hacks into the CIA's mainframe the is a list of 'Black Ops' which includes the 'Outcome' programme from *The Bourne Legacy*

Unfortunately, I cannot find a complete screenshot of this but here is one of the list, with 'OUTCOME' just out of the of the shot somewhere below 'SPEARFISH...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `Outcome` and `LARX` programs are visible on the screen when Bourne looks through the USB Nicky provided in Berlin. [image]